# Macro to add data from another sheet to last row behaves erratically?

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook has 4 tabs.  I need to move data from all three tabs to a summary sheet.  The code works until I add the section to pull from the second sheet.  (I haven't bothered trying to pull from the 3rd sheet yet as I can't get this to work). The source range is different for all three sheets and well as the columns to copy.

This code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  Upon first opening spreadsheet, it will work correctly the first time.  Subsequent times, the data from source2 is overwriting the data from source1 starting with row 1, or it adds the data after a few blank rows.

I have tried several variations I have found in forums with the same results.

```
Sub SendToSummary()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Source2 As Worksheet
    Dim Source3 As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Designations
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pool Cleaners")
    Set Source2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Service Technicians")
    Set Source3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PCQC Bonello Commissions")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    lastrow = Target.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    
        
    Sheets("Summary").Cells.Clear
    Sheets("Summary").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

    
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("N:N")   ' Do column N moving hours to summary sheet
        If c > 0 Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Columns("I:Q").Copy
           Target.Rows(j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
    
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    With ActiveSheet 'delete blank hours & headers
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("f1", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, ""
    On Error Resume Next
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter 1, "hours"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
      End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    
    k = lastrow
    For Each c In Source2.Range("Q:Q") 'copying tech commissions over
        If c > 0 Then
            Source2.Rows(c.Row).Columns("k:s").Copy
            Target.Rows(k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next c
              
    End Sub
```

Comment: In your last loop you're looping over Source2 but copying from Source3.    You're also using both `lastrow` and `j` to determine which row to paste to - you need to chose one of those...

Comment: oh, the source2/source3 was a last minute renaming for the order i was doing them in, but didn't attempt to run it like that! thanks for pointing it out

Comment: There's no need for `lastrow` here - you clear the sheet immediately after setting it, so it's no longer relevant.  Just keep using/incrementing `j`

Comment: What do you mean I clear the sheet after setting it? I fill up the sheet with data from source1, then need to add data from source2, 3, etc to the existing data. I only clear the sheet if I run the macro again (say i've made corrections to the sources or added more)

Comment: `Sheets("Summary").Cells.Clear` runs after `lastrow = Target.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row + 1`

Comment: `With Range("f1", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` - this line is not tied to the surrounding "with" block - it will work as long as Target is active, but it's best not to rely on that.  Also - it's good practice to cancel your `On Error Resume Next` with `On Error Goto 0` as soon as you don't need it, or you run the risk of ignoring other types of error which you'd want to know about.

Comment: I've made adjustments based on your feedback and the macro seems to be running correctly on multiple tries now.  However, I don't understand what you mean about the line not being tied to the "with" block, or how I could rework that section to be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your question in the comments:

Here:

```vb
Sheets("Summary").Select
With ActiveSheet 'delete blank hours & headers
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("f1", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) '<<<<< here
        .AutoFilter 1, ""
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter 1, "hours"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
     End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Your outer `With` object is `Activesheet`, so anything in the `With` block which is  preceded by `.` is linked to that object.  The `Range` calls in the flagged line are not explicitly tied to the `With` block object (since they have no `.`) except by "accident" because the `With` block object in this case is the active sheet, and unqualified `Range` references in a regular code module default to the ActiveSheet.

Your code "works" as long as "Summary" is active, but will break otherwise.

You could do something like this, and avoid needing to activate the sheet:

```vb
With Target 'delete blank hours & headers
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("f1", .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) '<<<<< here
        .AutoFilter 1, ""
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Goto 0
        .AutoFilter 1, "hours"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Goto 0
     End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: So is `Target.Range("F1", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` correct? And would that eliminate the `With` ?

Comment: See my addition above

Comment: That's so simple.  Thank you for all your help!! much appreciated